# can't merge cells in VBA 2007 worksheet notactive

Tags: excel, vba, merge, range

i'm trying to create a button that makes an automatic work arrangement according to a date and year i give him.
it creates a new sheet with the name that in the string - year

```
Sub Create_Arran_Click()

Dim year As String
Dim sdate As Date
Dim row As Integer

year = Worksheets("Main").Cells(17, 4)
sdate = Worksheets("Main").Cells(18, 4)
Sheets.Add.Name = year

For i = 1 To 56
row = ((i - 1) * 12) + 2
Worksheets(year).Cells(row, 1) = "week " & i
Worksheets(year).Cells(row + 1, 1) = "day"
Worksheets(year).Cells(row, 1).Font.Bold = True
For j = 2 To 15

    (!)Range(Cells(row, j), Cells(row, (j + 1))).Merge 
    Worksheets(year).Cells(row, j) = sdate + (j - 2)
    (!)Range(Cells(row + 1, j), Cells(row + 1, j + 1)).Merge 
    Worksheets(year).Cells(row + 1, j) = Weekday(sdate + (j - 2), vbSunday)

j = j + 2
Next
sdate = sdate + 7
Next'
```

the problem is that the rows that marked with '!' are not doing the merge in the 'year' sheet. i tried several things like:

```
          'Worksheets(year).Range(Cells(row, j), Cells(row, (j + 1))).Merge
```

or
               sheets(year).Range(Cells(row, j), Cells(row, (j + 1))).Merge
or 
               Worksheets(year).activate

but nothing helps
anyone?

Comment: That code works for me in Excel 2010 - you say rows marked with '!' aren't working, but I see no rows marked.

Comment: i edit it again. does it merge the cells it in the worksheet(year)?

Comment: Yes, it merges the two cells for each `Date` and it merges the two cells for each `Day` in each of the 56 weeks on `worksheet(year)`

Comment: Simply activate the worksheet before merging (each worksheet to have merged cells must be activated before merging)

Comment: thanks - how is it supposed to be written? worksheet(year).activate.range...merge or a different line: worksheet(year).activate and then range...merge?

Comment: @Daniel I have run the code exactly as written, from a button the sheet, from a button on a userform and directly from the VBA editor and it works each time. At no time is the worksheet activated in code. OP has stated that he has tried the 'worksheets(year).activate' code.

Comment: @Gilad, Separate lines, the activation comes first.

Comment: i did this:        Worksheets(year).Activate
        Range(Cells(row, j), Cells(row, (j + 1))).Merge
        Worksheets(year).Cells(row, j) = sdate + (j - 2)
and it still doesn't work - what am i doing wrong? the code is written in the sheet code and not in a module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you reference a range from another sheet you need to say where it is when calling Range AND Cells

So rather than writing

```
Worksheets(year).Range(Cells(row, j), Cells(row, (j + 1))).Merge
```

Do this

```
with Worksheets(year)
.Range(.Cells(row, j), .Cells(row, (j + 1))).Merge
end with
```

Notice how I reference the sheet both when I call Range and Cells

Answer (score 1):

you need to refer to the sheet when you refer cells also in this format

sheets("year").Range(sheets("year").Cells(i, j), sheets("year").Cells(i, j+3)).merge

Sooraj

Answer (score 0):

When you do `Range(Cells(row, j), Cells(row, (j + 1))).Merge` you are taking the sheet where the code is writen, and it may not be "Year" worksheet.

Try doing `Worksheets(Year).Range(Cells(row, j), Cells(row, (j + 1))).Merge` instead.

If necessary, activate before:

```
Worksheets(Year).Activate
Worksheets(Year).Range(Cells(row, j), Cells(row, (j + 1))).Merge
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - unfortunately i already tried both of them and it is not working, this -  Worksheets(Year).Range(Cells(row, j), Cells(row, (j + 1))).Merge - can not compile ):